# PayPal Pro Button not working - returns to blank event form

Tags: wordpress, civievent, paypal

We use PayPal Pro for our event pages. This is what is currently happening:
Person fills in the event registration profile.
Person clicks PayPal checkout button, enters their PayPal information.
When the person clicks Continue, they are returned to our registration form. All of the profile information they had entered is gone. If they reenter all the info and click continue, they get an error message saying they didn't fill in the credit card information.

If people enter their credit card information on our registration form (instead of using the PayPal check out button), everything works.

How do we fix the PayPal button? Or can we remove it?

We are using CiviCRM 5.12.0 with WordPress and PayPal Pro.

Answer (score 2):

I encountered this bug myself last week and fixed it; I forgot about this post until @herb posted a comment on it.

The fix will be in CiviCRM 5.25+, but the bug is logged as https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/financial/issues/119, and [the fix](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/16692/files) is incredibly simple to apply.

Comment: Great news Jon! I was going to start debugging which is a pain for payment processors.

Answer (score 1):

Removing the button is against the PayPal TOU...but I have an extension that does it anyway.  Install [Hide PayPal Express Checkout](https://github.com/MegaphoneJon/coop.palantetech.module.hidepaypalexpresscheckout) and call it a day.

Actually...I wrote this a LONG time ago for a client that doesn't use event pages.  It should work on contribution pages but might need some tweaking for event pages.

Comment: Is there another solution besides removing the button? I'd prefer not to violate TOU if possible.

Comment: I reported the issue https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/issues/1641. Someone needs to debug why and come up with a fix.

Comment: @herb By complete chance I encountered and fixed this bug last week!  I updated your ticket.